# How to create feed groups programmatically in getstream.io using java?

Tags: java, getstream-io

Is there any Java API, library to programmatically create feed groups in getstream.io. All samples are pointing to dashboard to create them manually. Is there any programatic way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

you can only create groups in the dashboard. However, once you have a group defined you can instantiate feeds from that group realtime through the API. So as an example, if you created a feed group called fruit, you could then create feeds through the API for apples, oranges, pears, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so basically the only way to add / remove groups through dashboard? I was assuming, I will supply the getstreasm.io app id and access key to my application, and it will programatically create the necessary groups at startup.